# How to configure JmsMessagingTemplate to use MappingJackson2MessageConverter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms

I am looking at using `JmsMessagingTemplate` instead of `JmsTemplate` because I would like to use `convertSendAndReceive`. The messages should be send in JSON format. I am having difficulties convincing `JmsMessagingTemplate` to use `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` instead of the `SimpleMessageConverter`. The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#messaging.jms.sending) seems to indicate that having a bean for `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` is enough to have it been used.

I created a small reproducing project. Given the following files:

```xml
// pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```java
// Payload.java
package com.example.demo;

public class Payload {
    public String value;

    public Payload(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public Payload() {}
}

// Listener.java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;

@Component
public class Listener {

    @JmsListener(destination = "my-topic")
    public String listen(Message msg) throws JMSException {
        System.out.println(msg.getJMSDestination().toString());
        return "reply";
    }
}


// Sender.java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Sender {
    @Autowired
    JmsMessagingTemplate jms;

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void send() {
        final var result = jms.convertSendAndReceive("my-topic", new Payload("hello"), String.class);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}


// Config.java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;

@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter messageConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not convert 'GenericMessage [payload=com.example.demo.Payload@5f8dd865, headers={id=d39f719b-4120-ceb1-a2ea-6468aeed5e13, timestamp=1639682065670}]'; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert object of type [com.example.demo.Payload] to JMS message. Supported message payloads are: String, byte array, Map<String,?>, Serializable object.
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate$MessagingMessageCreator.createMessage(JmsMessagingTemplate.java:476) ~[spring-jms-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSendAndReceive(JmsTemplate.java:915) ~[spring-jms-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.lambda$sendAndReceive$11(JmsTemplate.java:896) ~[spring-jms-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.executeLocal(JmsTemplate.java:954) ~[spring-jms-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.sendAndReceive(JmsTemplate.java:894) ~[spring-jms-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(JmsMessagingTemplate.java:411) ~[spring-jms-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(JmsMessagingTemplate.java:297) ~[spring-jms-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(JmsMessagingTemplate.java:349) ~[spring-jms-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(JmsMessagingTemplate.java:319) ~[spring-jms-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(JmsMessagingTemplate.java:305) ~[spring-jms-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at com.example.demo.Sender.send(Sender.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:344) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:229) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:166) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.ready(EventPublishingRunListener.java:114) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$ready$6(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:82) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.ready(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:82) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:563) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert object of type [com.example.demo.Payload] to JMS message. Supported message payloads are: String, byte array, Map<String,?>, Serializable object.
    at org.springframework.jms.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.toMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:79) ~[spring-jms-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.createMessageForPayload(MessagingMessageConverter.java:144) ~[spring-jms-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.toMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:111) ~[spring-jms-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate$MessagingMessageCreator.createMessage(JmsMessagingTemplate.java:473) ~[spring-jms-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Debugging the `JmsMessagingTemplate` I end up in `AbstractMessageSendingTemplate` where the message converter is of type `SimpleMessageConverter` in stead of the expected `MappingJackson2MessageConverter`.

I hope someone can show me the missing configuration or relevant docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting the MessageConverter to the `jmsMessagingTemplate` bean that you're using. You need to set the message converter using `setJmsMessageConverter()` method before calling `convertSendAndReceive()`.

Here's the javadocs - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsMessagingTemplate.html#setJmsMessageConverter-org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter-